# Set ports for container in docker for docker-client for java

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose

I can't set publicPort and privatePort for container in docker.
I creating docker container with java library `docker-client` for java 
https://github.com/spotify/docker-client

I already had created a docker image locally "mobillogix/selenium-chrome".

DockerClient docker = DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().build();

```
    // Bind container ports to host ports
    final String[] ports = {"44444", "59004"};
    final String[] ports1 = {"4444", "5900"};

    final Map<String, List<PortBinding>> portBindings = new HashMap<String, List<PortBinding>>();
    for (String port : ports) {
        List<PortBinding> hostPorts = new ArrayList<PortBinding>();
        hostPorts.add(PortBinding.of("0.0.0.0", port));
        portBindings.put(port, hostPorts);
    }


    final HostConfig hostConfig = HostConfig.builder().portBindings(portBindings).build();

    final ContainerConfig containerConfig = ContainerConfig.builder()
            .hostConfig(hostConfig)
            .image("mobillogix/selenium-chrome").exposedPorts(ports1)
            .build();

    final ContainerCreation creation = docker.createContainer(containerConfig);
    final String id = creation.id();

    // Start container
    docker.startContainer(id);

    final List<Container> containers = docker.listContainers();

    webDriver();

    // Kill container
    docker.killContainer(id);

    // Remove container
    docker.removeContainer(id);
```

This code create container:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                NAMES
6beec961dfcf        mobillogix/selenium-chrome   "/opt/bin/entry_point"   4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        4444/tcp, 5900/tcp   elegant_kare
```

with ports

> 4444/tcp, 5900/tcp

but I want to create container with ports:

> 0.0.0.0:44444->4444/tcp, 0.0.0.0:59004->5900/tc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://github.com/spotify/docker-client), the right syntax here would be:

```
hostPorts.add(PortBinding.of("0.0.0.0", 44444));
portBindings.put(4444, hostPorts);

hostPorts.add(PortBinding.of("0.0.0.0", 59004));
portBindings.put(5900, hostPorts);
```

What you perform in your loop is this:

```
hostPorts.add(PortBinding.of("0.0.0.0", 44444));
portBindings.put(44444, hostPorts);

hostPorts.add(PortBinding.of("0.0.0.0", 59004));
portBindings.put(50004, hostPorts);
```